# Why changes in sublist are reflected in the original list?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, sublist

I know that `Collections` in Java are mutable when you pass them through references.
I want to know exactly what happens in memory addresses of original-list and sublist/s of it.
Do the sublist and original list refer to the same object?

Following is code sample reflecting changes made in sublist to main original list.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add(1, "3");

List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>(list);

list.addAll(list2);

list2 = list.subList(2, 5);
list2.clear();               //Changes are made to list

System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [`JavaDoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) on the matter:

> List subList(int fromIndex,
>                   int toIndex)
>
> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex,
>   exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is
>   empty.) **The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural
>   changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and
>   vice-versa**. The returned list supports all of the optional list
>   operations supported by this list.

The sub list will point to the same elements present within the original list, thus, any changes made through the sub list will be reflected within the original list since you are changing the same objects.

EDIT: As per your comment, assume that the `original list` has the following references: `0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05` and these map to locations in memory where objects exist.

Doing `sublist(0, 2)` on the above will yield a list which contains pointers to the following memory locations `0x00 0x01 0x02` which are the same as in `original list`.

What this means is that if you do `sublist.get(0).setFoo(foo)`, this will in turn seek out the object present at `0x00` and set some property. However, `0x00` is also being referenced to by `original list`, which is why changing the sub list means that you will be changing the source list **since both lists point to the same objects**. The same also holds should you change your elements through `original list`.

Comment: what do you mean what happens in memory? just like anything that references the same thing does. there's nothing special here

Comment: @ShubhamKharde: I've tried to expand my answer. If you still have issues, you will need to look into how references in general work.

Comment: @Brandon Ling how will the changes reflect? Both the references, substring and main list must be pointing to same object? Or the sublist object contains something like _pointers_ to store the reference where corresponding object value is stored?

Comment: Minor question, why does the list in `sublist(0, 2)` have 4 elements in it?

Comment: @phlaxyr: That was a long overdue typo. Fixed.

Comment: sublist(0, 2) has two elements 0 and 1. The element with index 2 is excluded according to documentation. So why you have 3 references (0x00 0x01 0x02)?

Answer (score 4):

In line

```
list2 = list.subList(2, 5);
```

you are calling `subList` method of `ArrayList` referred from `list`. Its code looks like this

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    subListRangeCheck(fromIndex, toIndex, size);
    return new SubList(this, 0, fromIndex, toIndex);
}
```

so after confirming valid range list2 will store result of

```
new SubList(this, 0, fromIndex, toIndex);
```

where `private class SubList extends AbstractList<E>` is class defined inside `ArrayList` and code of this constructor looks like this

```
SubList(AbstractList<E> parent,
        int offset, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.parentOffset = fromIndex;
    this.offset = offset + fromIndex;
    this.size = toIndex - fromIndex;
    this.modCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;
}
```

so its `parent` field will store reference to original `ArrayList` (`new SubList(this, ...)`).

Now when you call

```
list2.clear();
```

code of `clear()` method inherited by `SubList` from `AbstractList` will be invoked

```
public void clear() {
    removeRange(0, size());
}
```

which will internally invoke `removeRange` overridden in `SubList`

```
protected void removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    checkForComodification();
    parent.removeRange(parentOffset + fromIndex,
                       parentOffset + toIndex);
    this.modCount = parent.modCount;
    this.size -= toIndex - fromIndex;
}
```

So as you see, as result you are calling

```
parent.removeRange(parentOffset + fromIndex,
                   parentOffset + toIndex);
```

where as you remember `parent` holds reference to ArrayList on which `subList` was called. So effectively by calling `clear` you are invoking `removeRange` from original list from which you created sublist.

Comment: Thanks. People just dont want to get into deep and if their answer is not accepted they downvote the question.For those who downvoted the question,this is the answer i was expecting and they must adhere to what is asked in question.

Comment: @ShubhamKharde People don't usually down-vote just because their answer was not accepted, but rather if they think that question is unclear, or doesn't contain some proof or research. To be honest I also wasn't sure if that is the answer you ware looking for, but since I decided that it would be good to refresh my memory about collections I decided to do some research and post them as answer.

Comment: @ShubhamKharde It looks similar, he is describing code using memory address, I am showing what methods, when, and on what references are called to show you main point, that in the end call `list2.clear()` will result in calling `removeRange` from original `list`.

Comment: Point is that `sibList` doesn't create list which copies references to all objects from original list, but simply remembers indexes of first and last element from list (range) which it should represent. So calling methods on subList is same as calling these methods on some range of original list.

Answer (score 3):

Here are simplified visualizations of a memory for the code sample based on the [java source code](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) as addition to Pshemo's great answer:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1");
list.add("2");
list.add(1, "3");

List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>(list);

list.addAll(list2);
```

[image]

---

```
list2 = list.subList(2, 5);
```

SubList has a reference to an original list with an offset to know where a sublist starts and a size to know where a sublist ends.

[image]

---

```
list2.clear();
```

Actions on list elements are forwarded to an original list.

[image]

Note that this elements are removed by coping reference from index 5 to index 2 and filling array's indexes 3, 4 and 5 with nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29).

> SubList returns a view of the portion of this list between the
>   specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex
>   and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list
>   is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list
>   are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
>   all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

So your list2 is just a sub-view of your orginal list.That is why, when you are clearing list2, you are losing corresponding values in orginal list.Check this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add(1, "3");
        List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>(list);
        list.addAll(list2);
        System.out.println(list);
        list2 = list.subList(2, 5);
        System.out.println(list2);
        list2.clear();               //Changes are made to list1
        System.out.println(list);

    }
```

O/P

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
```