# Does java have an equivalent of mysql's limit and offset for arraylists?

Tags: java, mysql, list, limit, offset

In MySQL you can do something like this:

```
select * from sometable order by id desc limit 3 offset 0;
```

Which would return the first 3 results. How is something like this achievable in java?

If I have an `ArrayList` of an odd amount of elements:

```
ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
ids.add("1");
ids.add("2");
ids.add("3");
ids.add("4");
ids.add("5");
ids.add("6");
ids.add("7");
ids.add("8");
ids.add("9");
ids.add("10");
ids.add("11");
```

How would one go about getting only 3 results from this `ArrayList` for each offset (or less than 3 if there are no more elements left)?

for example, say if the limit is always 3 and `offset = 0`:

> it should spit out 1,2,3

`if offset = 3`:

> 4,5,6

`offset = 6`:

> 7,8,9

`offset = 9`:

> 10,11

The way i'm currently doing it is by creating a subList of the list:

```
int endOf = offset+3;
ArrayList<String> ids2 = new ArrayList<String>(ids.subList(offset, endOf));
```

But it breaks when the offset is larger than the size of ids...

If this can't be done with arraylists is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT:**

Based on the two answers, Andy's method seemed to perform better:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
 //tried each method here
long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
```

Without streams:

```
40960
17167
13854
10240
```

With streams:

```
303584
118060
47284
40357
```

**EDIT2:**

The benchmark test above by no means should be relied on. For more info why see here: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: If you are using Guava, you might alternatively use [`Lists.partition`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-).

Comment: Your benchmark is way too naive. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just clamp the parameters of `subList`:

```
list.subList(
    Math.min(list.size(), offset),
    Math.min(list.size(), offset + limit))
```

If you find the syntax inconvenient, write a helper method, e.g.

```
<T> List<T> clampedSublist(List<T> list, int offset, int limit)
```

Comment: great solution too, but the stream example seems like the easier way to go in this case. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte one thing to bear in mind is that the stream approach creates a new list, whereas this just returns a view of the list, i.e. O(lim) storage Vs O(1).

Comment: Would you say this method is more efficient then?

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte yes.

Comment: Well i guess i'll mark this answer as the correct one considering it's the most efficient and doesn't require changing the pre-existing method. Cheers!

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte don't simply take my word for it though. Measure the difference in your application. If there is no significant difference, or the difference doesn't matter, choose the one you find easiest.

Comment: The difference should always matter, even if it's almost negligible. I ran a small test on the two methods and this method was indeed the one that performed the fastest. (as shown in the edit of my question)

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: @lexicore thanks, that answer is gold. Edited my question.

Comment: One thing you also have to consider is that `subList` gives you a *view* of the original list. From the JavaDoc: *The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.*
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540730/why-changes-in-sublist-are-reflected-in-the-original-list).
So if you need an independent list, you have to create a copy of the sublist (`new ArrayList<>(...)` or similar).

Answer (score 10):

This can be done with streams:

```java
List<Integer> result = 
    ids.stream()
       .skip(0)  // Equivalent to SQL's offset
       .limit(3) // Equivalent to SQL's limit
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> result = 
    ids.stream()
       .skip(0)  // Equivalent to SQL's offset
       .limit(3) // Equivalent to SQL's limit
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

skip should be `pageno` times `limit`

Comment: For this answer to be useful, further explanation would greatly assist.